# Type 'T' cannot be used to index type "Class"

Tags: typescript

I am looking to make a typescript generic of the `Parameters` for a specific class.

```
type Example<T> = Parameters<UserRepository[T]>[0]
```

However I get this error:

> Type 'T' cannot be used to index type "UserRepository"

also tried this:

```
type Example<T extends string> = Parameters<UserRepository[T]>[0]
```

I currently have this:

```
type Params = Parameters<UserRepository["members"]>[0] & 
              Parameters<UserRepository["contacts"]>[0] & 
              Parameters<UserRepository["user"]>[0]
```

I would like to create two generics `ClassMethod` and `ClassMethods`.

```
type ClassMethod<C, M> = string
type Param = ClassMethod<UserRepository, 'members'>
```

Or

```
type ClassMethod<T> = Parameters<UserRepository[T]>[0]
type Param = ClassMethod<'members'> // where the generic has `UserRepository `in it.
```

And

```
type ClassMethods<C, M> = string
type Params = ClassMethods<UserRepository, ['members', 'contacts', 'user']>
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve exactly? It's not really clear from your examples, because they also don't make a ton of sense to me. Maybe you can demonstrate a minimal example of what you want the resulting type to look like?

Comment: Hey @Evert Updated for the specific generics I am looking to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [`ClassMethod<'meow'>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=35#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOAlBAHA9hAlgF0yQE9oBvAKGiugFsFMB3aAChwC4zpgw8BlTAK4A7ACYcIeJDiEBzaAF8AlGXKVq8tVQaZMAMxbtOIzDP7Cx0CVNkLlFTQvIbyeIugTQAwuCgBZBHgAFpgiADwAKtAIAB54CKIwANYIRHpwiKgY2PiERAB80AC80AAKYEhgdHFIEKHwyGhYuATEANrhALp5rQAMHaqu7tAAotGV6CAexd6QEP5BIaEA5HSMS3lAA)

The first example is simple, the class is embeded in d

```
type ClassMethod<T extends keyof UserRepository> = Parameters<UserRepository[T]>[0]
```

### [`ClassMethod<UserRepository, 'meow'>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=51&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOAlBAHA9hAlgF0yQE9oBvAKGiugFsFMB3aAChwC4zpgw8BlTAK4A7ACYcIeJDiEBzaAF8AlGXKVq8tVQaZMAMxbtOIzDP7Cx0CVNkLlFTQvIbyeIugTQAwuCgBZBHgAFpgiADzA0AgAHngIojBgQkQANNAAKpExcSIwANYIRHpcAHzQALzQAApgSGB0sUgQ4QDaaQC6xc0ADG2qru7QAKJRdeggHhXekBD%20QSGh8MhoWLgExKkA5HSMG8VAA)

```
type ClassMethod<c extends any, T extends keyof c> = Parameters<c[T]>[0]
```

### [`ClassMethods<UserRepository, 'meow' | 'woof'>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOAlBAHA9hAlgF0yQE9oBvAKGiugFsFMB3aAChwC4zpgw8BlTAK4A7ACYcIeJDiEBzaAF8AlGXKVq8tVQaZMAMxbtOIzDP7Cx0CVNkLlFTQvIbyAehfQAgjAEQBYEAA0lggI0AAWeHjoEGxuEmDAANaYAG7IuiCMAHTAmDQuAI4CCBI4mEIQLgCsAAwAzADsACwAnDUAHC6SYBW6hDQAtMJlQgN4ROgIY5gD0njIiMB4I2MTCOTjk3BCIwAqmACSQvNIi8vlADywAHzQALzQasyw0AgAHvOiMD0kAPwsiQ4sEUd2uKUwOBE0A4QgQaSQynenxEMGYzEB0GkumQ0AOILBEJEyn+B2h0Fh8NUm1CAGFwFAALIIPBhTAoi40oIM14fBBfaCJBBEPTQGm3B6wHblfZHE5nEYXCjUaAAbQA0pihNAGQBdDg09U6nnI1HMLLmsBIGQxaA-FU65Sg21CIjE6AABUtYDoco5huuKpqRphcOQThVuuuVLWHq9NBgD09SG9zIWV0QqAw2HwhCIKoARHRGPmdQGg9AAGSPZVJlO++DINBYXAEYgF7R6EtlnXRrZJ+P3UX0iBMllsiDpxtZlu5oIAciLDDn0AAPtA5x3dHOo653AB5JCY-TCgTQJAIfwgEgMHp4Z22pDJojmrIbGN0yAj5mslEAJg5XLGnyKKeI+YBEBcgrCvoYritseyHMcCwIEsCpKtQ6qatqKpCAINAAEbIDqeqioaQH8miL6WtaHB2g69y3D8bq1j6aYGmqpaBsG5Khkg4YMjheGEUgxE7tSsZIPGv6Dh+jLfuO-4NpmzY5sQQQqgu9BLvOm5zqWQA)

```
class UserRepository {
    meow (i: { catSound: string }) {

    }
    woof (i: { dogSound: string }) {

    }
}

// As usual, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type ClassMethods<C, M extends keyof C> = UnionToIntersection<{
    [K in M]: C[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? Parameters<C[K]>[0] : never
}[M]>

type Parms = ClassMethods<UserRepository, 'meow' | 'woof'>

// Or if you really want an array...
type ClassMethods2<C, M extends Array<keyof C>> = UnionToIntersection<{
    [K in M[number]]: C[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? Parameters<C[K]>[0] : never
}[M[number]]>

type Parms2 = ClassMethods2<UserRepository, ['meow', 'woof']>
```

Special thank you to `Gerrit Birkeland` on [typescript gitter](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=5dbf643afb4dab784a5bda73).